# How to create a CSV file controlled by Start- and Stop-Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, button

I want to design a windows form application with having my data (approx. 70k values) in an array to transfer it to a csv file in minimal time, the csv file path and name to be given by the windows form application.

The data transfer is done only when first button named start is pressed and it should stop when second button stop is pressed irrespective of  number of values.

Here is the code:

```
public static void Write(double[] data, string outputPath)
{ 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", data[i]));
    }
    File.WriteAllText(outputPath, sb.ToString());
}
```

and this is the function I am using which has the varibale dscaledData which is an array. I want to take values from this array and store it in a csv file

```
Write(dScaledData, @csvadd);
```

The @ part shows the csv path with name 
The data values stored in dscaledData variable is very large approx. 70k

Comment: well this is the code i am using for csv writing but not able to link it with button

Comment: So? What is your question?

Comment: @JITINMALHOTRA I dont see any code, add it to the question please.

Comment: public static void Write(double[] data, string outputPath)
        {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", data[i]));
            }
            File.WriteAllText(outputPath, sb.ToString());
        }                                                                                                                                                     Write(dScaledData, @csvadd);

Comment: 1) to your question, not a comment. 2) you need to change to a) writing line by line and b) in another thread if you want to be able to stop it from a stop button

Comment: @JITINMALHOTRA As I said, add it to the opening post, this is barely readable

Comment: @Syren please see the code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the stop button to somehow break your write loop. But as it is, it will keep running and indeed block the ui thread. So you need to run the write loop in a different thread..

There are various way to do it in .NET, e.g. a `Task.Factory`, `threads` or a `BackgroundWorker`.

Here is a simple but effective implementation using a `Task.Factory`:

We create a class level variable `stopped` which we set and reset from the `Buttons`. There are other, more involved ways to cancel a `Task`, [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but this is good enough for the purpose..

For my tests I also create dummy data..

```
private void cb_Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  stopped = true;   // this will be checked in our output loop   }

private void cb_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stopped = false;
    // create my test data..
    List<double> data = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) data.Add((i+ 1d) / i * 1d );
    string filename = "D:\\xxxxx.txt";

    // this is an optional callback to provide feedback. 
    // It obviuosly slows things down greatly..
    Action<int> callback = (value) => st_lines.Invoke(new Action(() 
                         => st_lines.Text = value + " lines written.."));
    // now we start the write loop in another task..
    // ..passing in our data and (optinally) the callback
    Task myFirstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() 
                     => Write(data.ToArray(), filename, callback));
}

static bool stopped = true;   // our flag

public static void Write(double[] data, string outputPath, Action<int> aCallback)
{    // your write loop
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if (stopped) break;   // our new test
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", data[i]));
        aCallback( i );       // optional callback
    }
    File.WriteAllText(outputPath, sb.ToString());
}
```

A few notes about the timing situation:

Adding **70k** lines to a `StringBuilder` should not take a lot of time. Look at my code: I had to crank the test data up to **10M** lines to even be able to press the stop button on my machine!

Maybe the creation of the data is the bottleneck or maybe it is the writing to disk..? Or maybe there is no bottleneck?? You should understand this before you decide on an implementation!

If other parts are identified as the bottlenaeck you would have to change the code accordingly to break out of the other loops..

I have added the callback mechanism so you can see how you can bring information about the progress of the task back to the UI thread. It should help your users decide on whether stopping the task makes sense..

But adding the callback slows things down a lot, so instead of calling it for every single line you could do it like this: `if (i % 1000 == 0 ) aCallback(i);` and only update the progress label (or a `ProgressBar`, of course) every 1000 lines.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, please tell me is it necessary to add callback and what this callback function is  doing (yes it's mentioned optional), but still if you had added then there may be some logic behind that, if you can please explain me that, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you don't __need__ the callback. But as you want your users to be able to press a stop button, it might be helpful to tell them just how far the output has been processed. As such an information must be __displayed in the UI thread__ you can't do so __in the task__.  BTW: Do not do it like I did! Telling the user about every single line slows everything down greatly! Instead you could write it like this: `if (i % 1000 == 0 ) aCallback(i);` and only update the progress label (or a progressbar, of course) every 1000 lines.

Comment: thank you very much this what i want to do with my application, tested with my app and its just wow!!!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) for this. It is exactly what you Need.

Do not use File.WriteAllText, but use File.WriteLine in the worker-thread.

In my opinion 70k lines is not very much and if your amount of data doesnt grow substantially in the future, a human will not be able to start/stop unless you artificially pause the writer thread with a `Thread.Sleep()`